# How can I create instance Dynamically with parameter constructor resolve using autofac DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, dynamic-programming

my code look like this

```
private void installData()
{
    var dataInstallServices = new List<IDataInstallationService>(); 
    var dataInstallServiceTypes=_typeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IDataInstallationService>();

    foreach (var dataInstallServiceType in dataInstallServiceTypes)
        dataInstallServices.Add((IDataInstallationService)Activator.CreateInstance(dataInstallServiceType));

    foreach (var installServie in dataInstallServices)
        installServie.InstallData();
}
```

my problem is

```
dataInstallServices.Add((IDataInstallationService)Activator.CreateInstance(dataInstallServiceType,"parameters resolve using autofac"))
```

I register all dependency but I am getting **No parameterless constructor defined for this object.** Exception

Comment: Why are you using reflection to instantiate your services as opposed to Autofac? From what I interpret, you already have all the dependencies registered with Autofac.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoFac you shouldn't need to use Activator to create instances.

Say what you are trying to do above lives in a class called `DataService` that has the following dependencies:

```
public class DataInstallerA : IDataInstaller {
  public DataInstallerA(SubDependencyA a){}
}
public class DataInstallerB : IDataInstaller  {
  public DataInstallerA(SubDependencyB b){}
}
```

With the following AutoFac registrations:

```
builder.RegisterType<SubDependencyA>();
builder.RegisterType<SubDependencyB>();
builder.RegisterType<DataInstallerA>().As<IDataInstaller>();
builder.RegisterType<DataInstallerA>().As<IDataInstaller>();
builder.RegisterType<DataService>();
```

Your DataService could then look like:

```
public class DataService
{
  private IEnumerable<IDataInstaller> _dataInstallers;

  public DataService(IEnumerable<IDataInstaller> dataInstallers) {
    _dataInstallers = dataInstallers;
  }

  public void Install() {
    foreach (var installer in _dataInstallers)
      installer.InstallData();
  }
}
```

The `DataService` isn't concerned with having to know how to create all of the `IDataInstaller` instances, AutoFac can do that, it just needs a collection of them.

Note that even though you didn't actually register the `IEnumerable<IDataInstaller>` AutoFac provides some extra registrations implicitly when you register a type. See http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html.

Answer (score -1):

While using `Activator.CreateInstance(Type t)` method you should make sure the type has parameterless consturctor available to type you are passing to its parametere otherwise it is gonna throw an exception that you got.

**Why default consturctor is not there?**

When you specify constructor with parameter in class default constructor is removed by compiler.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test() //will give you compile time error.
        Test t1 = new Test(""); //should work fine.

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test(string a)
    {
    }
}
```

Use another overloaded method to pass constructor params there like below:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2);
```

MSDN documentation for that method is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `IDataInstallationService` type may have any No of parameter .My question is how can I resolve it dynamically ?

Comment: @MuhdAlavu You are allowed to pass n parameters to the `CreateInstance` methods.

Comment: @MuhdAlavu look at here for more on msdn documentation.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.